# R geom_bar labellng sum of weights

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar

this is my reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydf<-data.frame(a = rep(c(1:3), each=2),
                 b = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5))

mydf %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = a)) +
    geom_bar(aes(weight=b))

# and this is a variant getting the same result   
  mydf %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = a, weight=b)) +
    geom_bar()
```

Now I want to add the text labels `geom_text()` with corresponding values (sum of weights) on top of the bars.

The way I would like to achieve that is by labeling the data without creating a new dataframe (and then using `geom_col` in combination with `geom_text()`) but instead following the stream of the code drafted above.

It might be a trivial issue but I'm somehow tied in a knot with the idea to follow a sort of `afert_stat` approach but without getting to any viable solution so far.
I would like to understand how it is possible (and eventually, in fact, if it is!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `stat = 'count'` inside `geom_text`, and you need to make sure that `b` is mapped to the `weight` aesthetic in this layer; either directly or, as in this example, inherited from the main `ggplot` call to save on typing.

```r
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = a, weight = b)) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)), stat = 'count', nudge_y = 0.1)
```

[image]

---

Or, if this seems a little convoluted, just use `b` as your y axis values. You can use `stat = 'summary'` to get the labels in the right place:

```r
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack') +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(y)), stat = 'summary', 
            fun = 'sum', nudge_y = 0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it works!
But I'm struggling to understand the passing of that `stat='count'`'.
I'm a little disoriented by that verb `count` because I'm always thinking of a `sum`. Could you please clarify that? I would be very grateful to you for that.

Comment: @maxbre each `geom` layer in ggplot takes the data and performs a transformation on it according to its `stat` argument. By default, most geoms, including `geom_text`, use `stat = "identity"`, meaning that the data are left untransformed - you supply the x coordinates and y coordinates values yourself. In contrast, `geom_bar` uses `stat = 'count'` by default. You only need to supply the x coordinates, and the stat will count how many instances of each x coordinate there is to calculate the y coordinate of the bar.

Comment: @maxbre Adding a `weight` aesthetic means creating a count of `a` _weighted_ by `b`, which of course is equivalent to the sum of `b`, as you say. However, since the aesthetic that we are asking for is a count of `a` weighted by `b`, it is called `count`.

Comment: yes, the problem here is that I'm asking for a `sum` of the weights; and that means in `geom_bar` is achieved by a combination of `weight` passed as an `aes` and the default `stat='count'`, which in this particular case in fact means a `sum`. Sorry but it sounds a little convoluted to me, but that's it (as far as I understand)

Comment: @maxbre it _is_ a little convoluted. If all you are trying to do is sum the values of b then you could simply use `geom_col` with `y = b` and stack the bars instead. (`geom_col` is the same as `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`.

Comment: yes, you mean something like: `mydf %>%  ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b)) + geom_col(position = "stack")`;
but how to label the bar in this case?

Comment: @maxbre I have never really understood why people are so keen to get ggplot to do their data manipulation _and_ draw their plots, even if it means tying themselves in knots by trying to do something that is incredibly easy using other R functions. I tend to format my data the way I want it using functions designed for that purpose, then use ggplot to draw the result.

Comment: @maxbre but see my update - you can use `stat = 'summary'` in `geom_text`

Comment: That's great, thank you. By the way in this case I do agree with you about the convenience to approach the problem differently.